# Why do they initialize pointers this way?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-leaks, memory-management

In almost all of the books I read and examples I go through I see pointers initialized this way.  Say that I have a class variable **NSString *myString** that I want to initialize.  I will almost always see that done this way:

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] init];
        self.myString = tempString;
        [tempString release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Why can't I just do the following?

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I don't see why the extra **tempString** is ever needed in the first place, but I could be missing something here with memory management.  Is the way I want to do things acceptable or will it cause some kind of leak?  I have read the Memory Management Guide on developer.apple.com and unless I am just missing something, I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `self.myString` is a retained property, the second example has to be

```
-(id)init { 
    if (self = [super init]) { 
        self.myString = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    } 
    return self; 
}
```

or it will leak. I can only assume this is the case and the first example simply wants to avoid using `autorelease`.

Comment: So without autorelease, is the retain count 2 at the end?

Comment: Yup, `+1` for alloc and `+1` for the retained property.

Answer (score 4):

The second example is correct.

Assuming that `myString` is an ivar, the first example is actually wrong because it leaves `myString` with a dangling pointer (a pointer to a deallocated object). If it were `self.myString` that would be a different story.

Comment: Doh...you are correct, let me modify the original.  So there really is no difference between the two?